# How to map the servlet to a child route(like /blog)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using SpringMVC and tomcat, and I want to assign all the URLs beginning with `/blog` to my servlet, here is my code.

#### web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

    <display-name>Spring MVC XML Configuration Example</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:app-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>my-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:web-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>my-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/blog</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

#### web-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/blog/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/blog/" />

</beans>
```

#### app-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

</beans>
```

It doesn't work. I got a 404 when trying to access `/blog/index.html`. However, it worked if I changed the `servlet-mapping` part in `web.xml` to the following one.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> <!-- from /blog to / -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

But I don't want to do that, I only want the servlet to handle the URLs under `/blog`, can I do that? Should I change something in `web-config.xml` to make it work?

Comment: I think your problem is more about how to map a servletContext to the ROOT servletContext - if you did http://ip/myApp/blog/whatever it should work

Comment: You mapped the servlet only to `/blog`. `/blog` doesn't mean all URLs starting with `/blog`, it means the url `/blog` nothing more, nothing less.  `/blog/*` however does exactly mean that.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just tried changing `url-pattern` from `/blog` to `/blog/*`, still didn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Your page is now available a `/blog/blog/index.html` due to the way you have written your `<mvc:resource mapping"`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, it did work! I tried `/blog/index.html` before, the correct URL should be `/blog/blog/index.html`, as you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by M.Deinum in the comments, I should change the `servlet-mapping` part in `web.xml` to the following one:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/blog/*</url-pattern> <!-- notice the asterisk -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then change the `mvc:resource` part in `web-config.xml` to the following one.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/blog/" />
```

It's done, now open `/blog/index.html`, it should work now.